# How can I stop AppleScript from converting variables like "\087" into their octal form when passing through bash?

Tags: terminal, applescript, bash, xml

I have a program I'm using to write xml with variables, and it passes through AppleScript and bash to form the final xml. However, one of my variables usually begins with "024", "054", or other three digit codes that paired with the "\" forms an octal character, like "," for "\054". Once they are passed through bash, they become replaced with these octal characters. These variables need to stay the way they are, because they are part of a file path the xml ultimately pulls from. Unfortunately, I can't change these variables because they're linked to many other things working properly, and the backslashes are obligatory too. I want to know if there is a way to stop AppleScript from implementing octal encoding on this script as it passes through. A colleague recommended using iconv, which I tried unsuccessfully, partially because I'm not sure how to use it properly. Here is the AppleScript for reference:

`do shell script "echo \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?> <scratch project=\\\"TEST\\\"> <file>W:\\Sequences\\087_TLD_TL_Taking_The_Lead\\Shots\\TLD0640\\Versions\\MOV\\TLD0640_v0173.mov\\</file> </scratch>\" > ~/Desktop/Test.xml"`

And the output:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <scratch project="TEST"> <file>W:\Sequences87_TLD_TL_Taking_The_Lead\Shots\TLD0640\Versions\MOV\TLD0640_v0173.mov\</file> </scratch>`

Thank you for your help!

Edit: thanks Gordon Davisson for making the code viewable, and updated the codes to the bare minimum for reproducing the question.

Comment: It'd help a lot if you used code format (either indent code sections four spaces or enclose snippets in backticks) -- I tried to convert your question, but I'm not sure I got it right (it gives me an error in Script Editor). Also, please produce a [**minimal**, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, try to remove everything except what's necessary for someone else to reproduce the specific problem you're seeing, but leave in everything that's necessary.

Comment: Here is a minimal, reproducible example. `do shell script "echo \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?> <scratch project=\\\"TEST\\\"> <file>W:\\Sequences\\087_TLD_TL_Taking_The_Lead\\Shots\\TLD0640\\Versions\\MOV\\TLD0640_v0173.mov\\</file> </scratch>\" > ~/Desktop/Test.xml"`

Answer (score 1):

It looks like `do shell script` is running the script under the `sh` shell, which is actually `bash` in compatibility mode; in this mode, the builtin `echo` command apparently thinks it needs to interpret some escape (backslash) sequences. This is one of several features of `echo` that aren't consistent between versions/modes/etc; as the [POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) says, "It is not possible to use `echo` portably across all POSIX systems unless both `-n` (as the first argument) and escape sequences are omitted."

So, my first recommendation is to use `printf '%s\n` instead of `echo` (and the backslash will need to be doubled to get it past AppleScript):

```
do shell script "printf '%s\\n' \"<?xml version=\\\"1.0\\\" encoding=\\\"UTF-8\\\"?> <scratch project=\\\"TEST\\\"> <file>W:\\Sequences\\087_TLD_TL_Taking_The_Lead\\Shots\\TLD0640\\Versions\\MOV\\TLD0640_v0173.mov\\</file> </scratch>\" > ~/Desktop/Test.xml"
```

But even with `echo` getting into the act, you still have multiple confusing levels of quotes and escapes due to interpretation by AppleScript and the shell. I'd recommend storing the XML as an AppleScript variable (using just a single level of quoting/escaping, for consumption by AppleScript), then using `quoted form of` to quote/escape that for use in the shell command:

```
set XML_Content to "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\"?> <scratch project=\"TEST\"> <file>W:\\Sequences\\087_TLD_TL_Taking_The_Lead\\Shots\\TLD0640\\Versions\\MOV\\TLD0640_v0173.mov\\</file> </scratch>"

do shell script "printf '%s\\n' " & (quoted form of XML_Content) & " > ~/Desktop/Test.xml"
```